# How to prevent merge from reordering columns

Tags: r, sorting, merge

In the following example

```
x <- data.frame(code = 7:9, food = c('banana', 'apple', 'popcorn'))
y <- data.frame(food = c('banana', 'apple', 'popcorn'),
                isfruit = c('fruit', 'fruit', 'not fruit'))
```

I would like to do `x <- merge(x, y)`, but the problem is that `merge()` reorders the columns so that the `by` column (food) comes first. **How can I prevent this and have `merge(x, y)` use the same column order of x and just insert the new variable (isFruit) as the third column (i.e., "code, food, isFruit" instead of "food, code, isFruit")?**

I've tried this, to no avail:

```
merge(x, y, sort = F)
```

My workaround is to do this afterward

```
x <- x[c(2, 1, 3)]
```

Comment: I think your work around is the solution.

Comment: ...although it appears that `join` in the plyr package doesn't reorder columns.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's a generic version of your base workaround:

```
merge(x, y)[, union(names(x), names(y))]
```

Comment: Note that passing in `union` for col names only works on data frames - not data tables.

Comment: @Serenthia add `, with = FALSE` for `data.table`

Comment: This fails when merging using "by.x=" and "by.y=" and columns which differ in names. An ugly version of the above workaround is (using modified example data by OP with "food" and "food2" as merging columns):

`x <- data.frame(code = 7:9, food = c('banana', 'apple', 'popcorn')) ; y <- data.frame(food2 = c('banana', 'apple', 'popcorn'), isfruit = c('fruit', 'fruit', 'not fruit')) ; byY="food2" ; merge(x, y, by.x="food",by.y=byY)[, union(names(x), subset(names(y), names(y)!=byY))]`

Comment: for data.table `merge(x, y)[, union(names(x), names(y), with=F)]`

Answer (score 13):

`plyr` makes this easy:

```
 x <- data.frame(code = 7:9, food = c('banana', 'apple', 'popcorn'))
 y <- data.frame(food = c('banana', 'apple', 'popcorn'),
                isfruit = c('fruit', 'fruit', 'not fruit'))

library(plyr)
join(x,y)

        #GOOD 
#Joining by: food
#  code    food   isfruit
#1    7  banana     fruit
#2    8   apple     fruit
#3    9 popcorn not fruit

    #BAD  
# merge(x,y)
#     food code   isfruit
#1   apple    8     fruit
#2  banana    7     fruit
#3 popcorn    9 not fruit
```

Comment: `plyr` just solved a bunch of my problems at once. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap it in your custom function. For example :

```
merge.keep <- function(...,ord=union(names(x), names(y)))merge(...)[ord]
```

then for example:

```
merge.keep(x,y)
  code    food   isfruit
1    8   apple     fruit
2    7  banana     fruit
3    9 popcorn not fruit
```

*EDIT* I use @Eddi idea to set default values of ord.

Comment: -1 because this doesn't add anything to the OP - what OP wants is **not** having to specify the order manually

Comment: @eddi good catch even I disagree with the downvote( I find it a little bit sharp). My idea was to create a function that extend merge functions. I edit my answer using your good idea to set default values of order.

Comment: @agstudy hello, this solution does not work if I have data tables with different names (e.g. x = DT1, y = DT2) and if I merge on different columns on these data tables. Err msg: Error in as.vector(x) : object 'x' not found. Makes sense, because the data tables are not named x and y to begin with. I tried to find a workaround, but without success. Do you know how to adapt the solution that it works more generally on (more complicated) data table merges?

Answer (score 2):

If you only bring in one column and want to append it last then maybe `merge` is overkill and you can just do an assingment with a `match`-`[`indexing approach:

```
> x$isfruit <- y$isfruit[match(y$food, x$food)]
> x
  code    food   isfruit
1    7  banana     fruit
2    8   apple     fruit
3    9 popcorn not fruit
```

(There are no switches to throw in the merge function to do what you ask.)

Comment: Thanks for the input, but my real data involves two data frames with dozens of columns.

Answer (score 0):

I have another work around that I've used in the past:

```
x$target <- merge(x, y, by = "key", all = T)$target
```

This of course has drawbacks:

- It only merges one column at a time.
- It is manual and prone to error if you forget to manually change the column name in both places.
- It necessitates `all=TRUE` to protect against any unmerged elements.